# Square Connect CatalogObjectId

Tags: square

I'm developing an ASP.Net (C#) website for a brick and mortar business that uses Square as their POS. I'm trying to use the Square Checkout API. In creating the CreateOrderRequestLineItem, I need to set the CatalogObjectId of the item so that web sales/activity will reconcile to their in-person sales for those same items. I am not able to locate the CatalogObjectId on the square dashboard and I really don't want to make a call to the catalog API to hopefully get the correct item that the user has already selected the item. I've exported the list of items from the dashboard and I see a "token" column that looks like it might be a unique ID. Basically, I have two questions:

1. Is the token value from the export the CatalogObjectId?
2. If no, then how/where can I get the CatalogObjectId for a given item?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my answers -

1. No, Token value is not the CatalogObjectId
2. You can save the catalog items in your DB by calling "ListCatalog" api as -
   https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-listcatalog
   and then get CatalogObjectId by comparing the product names.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how it was in 2018 but I just used the token value as the  `catalog_object_id` and it seems to work fine.

From this url:
https://squareup.com/dashboard/items/library

Click "Actions" and select `Export Library` as `.xls` format.

First column in the spreadsheet is `token` and you can use those values as the `catalog_object_id`'s